# array of ActivityResultLaunchers<Intent> with named indexes

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my activity, I declare several ActivityResultLauncher which I must then pass as parameters of the constructor of a class, which gives things like:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> rangtGalleryActivityResultLauncher;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> rangtCameraActivityResultLauncher;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> stockCameraActivityResultLauncher;
 myparam = new myClass(
       rangtGalleryActivityResultLauncher,
       rangtCameraActivityResultLauncher,
       stockGalleryActivityResultLauncher,
       stockCameraActivityResultLauncher);
```

How could I do to simplify declarations and appeals?
For example, with an array whose indexes are named:

```
myArray[
        "rangtGallery" => ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> rangtGalleryActivityResultLauncher,
        "rangtCamera" => ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> rangtCameraActivityResultLauncher, ...
]
```

passing myArray as a parameter and calling

```
myArray["rangGallery"].launch()
```

?

All is fixed, nothing dynamic.

Comment: What are the actions of those intents? Can you share how do you create intents for each of those launchers? Knowing the intents' actions I can recommend you a compact way to handle the all results with just one launcher.

Comment: @Kozmotronik The migration from onActivityResult to ActivityResultContracts removing the resultCode, requires having as many ActivityResultLauncher as there are cases (in any case, that's what I've read everywhere).
I can personally have up to 6 in the same activity. It's very cumbersome to pass in parameters, and above all, it makes the code less readable to me.
If there is no other solution, I do like this, but if there is a way to group all this, I would like to know it, but in fact, it does not matter what my ActivityResultLauncher are used for.

Comment: You need to create an intent for each launcher don't you? Knowing this I was thinking that only one launcher would be enough to process all results within the same activity. All you need to know woul only the actions of your intents.